# Are Hashes ever on the stack in Crystal lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

In the Crystal language, are Hashes ever allocated on the stack? Or are they always 'heaped'? I could not find anything in the docs (https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.33.0/Hash.html - looked up on 19 Feb 2020). I see quite a few `malloc_*` in https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/master/src/hash.cr, but wasn't sure if there was optimization I was missing. I don't think the docs call it out explicitly - did a word-find in browser for 'heap', 'stack' and 'allocate' on https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.33.0/Hash.html... couldn't find anything.

Comment: Always on the heap. Hash inherits from Reference and Reference types are always allocated on the heap.

Comment: Anything `class` is on the heap in Crystal, https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/structs.html explains this.

Comment: There it is right in `reference.cr` --> ```#`Reference` is the base class of classes you define in your program.
# It is set as a class' superclass when you don't specify one:``` ... and indeed, `Hash` does not have an explicitly specified superclass. Thanks @asterite and @jonne-haß

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes are always heap allocated.

In Crystal, it depends on whether a object is of type [`Reference`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Reference.html) or [`Value`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Value.html). All objects that inherit from `Reference` are always allocated on the heap.

A hash is defined as [`class Hash(K, V)`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Hash.html). As class always inherits from `Reference`, hashes will always be heap allocated.

Value types like [`struct Int32`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Int32.html), where stack allocation is desirable, have to be defined as structs, so they do not inherit from `Reference` but from `Value`.